IMEI o Numero de serie del dispositivo movil Multi versiones de Android
Quisiera obtener el IMEI o numero de serie de un dispositivo Android 10, usando Android Studio o Xamarin .Forms.
Lo que busco con esto es encontrar alguna manera de ejecutar una aplicación solo en un dispositivo (tablet) asignado o identificado por alguna ID (imei o numero de serie), no se si se puede hacer de esta forma o alguna otra.
solo como prueba quiero que lo muestre el ID al iniciar la Aplicación
Gracias de antemano

Bienvenido . agrega lo que tratate o investigaste, revisa [ask].
